# pandas get last value of column x when column y is equal to z

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I create a pandas DataFrame with two columns, one of which contains some numbers and the other contains letters. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b': ['y','x','y','x','y', 'y']})
pprint(df)

   a  b
0  1  y
1  2  x
2  3  y
3  4  x
4  5  y
5  6  y
```

Now say that I want to make a third column (`c`) whose value is equal to the last value of `a` when `b` was equal to x. In the cases where a value of x was not encountered in `b` yet, the value in `c` should default to 0.

The procedure should produce pretty much the following result:

```
last_a = 0
c = []
for i,b in enumerate(df['b']):
    if b == 'x':
        last_a = df.iloc[i]['a']
    c += [last_a]

df['c'] = c
pprint(df)


   a  b  c
0  1  y  0
1  2  x  2
2  3  y  2
3  4  x  4
4  5  y  4
5  6  y  4
```

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this either with or without pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [140]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b': ['y','x','y','x','y', 'y']})

In [141]: df
Out[141]: 
   a  b
0  1  y
1  2  x
2  3  y
3  4  x
4  5  y
5  6  y
```

FInd out where column 'b' == x, then return the value in that column (not the location); this column is already the 'a' column

```
In [142]: df['c'] = df.loc[df['b']=='x','a'].apply(lambda v: v if v < len(df) else np.nan)
```

Fill the rest of the values forward, then fill holes with 0

```
In [143]: df['c'] = df['c'].ffill().fillna(0)

In [144]: df
Out[144]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  y  0
1  2  x  2
2  3  y  2
3  4  x  4
4  5  y  4
5  6  y  4
```